# Get File Extension C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-extension

I have a dropdown with list of file names. When a file name is selected in the dropdown I do the following

```
string filename = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
string path = "F:\\WorkingCopy\\files\\" + filename +".docx";
DownloadFile(path,filename);
```

In the file folder files may contain any extension . Since i have hard coded ".docx" in string path everything works fine. But I need to get the extension of the file name with the ddl.SelectedItem.Text alone. Can you tell me how to do this?

Things  I have
1.) File name without extension in

```
string filename = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
```

2.) Path where the file is located

```
string path = "F:\\WorkingCopy\\files\\" + filename
```

I am trying to get the file extension with these . Can any one suggest on this?

Comment: what if there are two files `filename.ext1` and `filename.ext2`?

Comment: There wont be such a situation in my case

Comment: I will have unique file names and extensions. I won't have such situation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles) like this:

```
string path = "F:\\WorkingCopy\\files\\";
string filename = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;

string existingFile = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, filename + ".*").FirstOrDefault();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(existingFile))
    Console.WriteLine("Extension is: " + Path.GetExtension(existingFile));
```

`Directory.EnumerateFiles` searches the `path` for files like `filename.*`. [`Path.GetExtension()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension) returns the extension of the found file.

---

In general, I prefer to use `EnumerateFiles()` instead of `GetFiles` because it returns an `IEnumerable<string>` instead `string[]`. This suggests that it only returns the matching files as needed instead searching all matching files at once. (This doesn't really matter in your case, just a general note).

Comment: I tried this. But I get this error Could not find a part of the path 'F:\WorkingCopy\files\filename'.  But the path exists

Comment: Thatswhy I showed what `path` and `filename` are in my example. Of course you use only `F:\WorkingCopy\files` as `path`, without the trailing `filename`.

Comment: @RenéVogt you should consider Joining paths to avoid OS incompatibilities. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3

Comment: @vishalsharma what exactly do you mean? `Path.Combine(filename, ".*")` will give me `f:\working...\filename\.*`, which is clearly not what I intend. Where in my code do I need to join paths? The path is already complete in `path`.

Comment: @vishalsharma ok, but that's just an example...for the question, OP already as a variable `path` containing the correct path. but you're right, in general one should use the methods in `Path` to handle file and directory names properly.

Comment: what will happen if more than one file with different extension exists in specified directory?

Comment: @VickyS that's what I asked OP in my very first comment, he said that won't happen (which would be no reason for me not to be prepared for it to  *do* happen). My code takes the first file in the sequence returned by `EnumerateFiles`. I can't tell which of the existing files this would be (first alphabetically or first to be found in the file system/api or whatever)...

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that with followed by line

```
 try
 {
    var extensions = new List<string>();
    var files = Directory.GetFiles("F:\\WorkingCopy\\files\\", filename + ".*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

    foreach (var tmpfile in files)
       extensions.Add(Path.GetExtension(tmpfile));

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
            throw ex;
}
```

will this help you?

Comment: This won't help me. Extension will be empty

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Directory.GetFiles` Method:

```
string result =  Directory.GetFiles(path, filename + ".*").FirstOrDefault();
```

see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)

here **" * "** is the `WildCard` and will search for the Filename starts with YourFileName.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Directory.GetFiles()` method. Something like this

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("F:\\WorkingCopy\\files\\", filename+".*");
```

This should get you an array of filenames with the same filename but different extensions. If you have only one, then you can always use the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split them by dot, For example, try this code

```
        string folder = @"F:\\WorkingCopy\\files\\";
        var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folder, filename + ".*");

        if (files.Any())
        {
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(files.First()).Substring(1);
        }
```

This code gives me result that the extension for this is txt file.

Comment: @RenéVogt OP want to know the filename from " "F:\\WorkingCopy\\files\\" + filename " what's wrong ?,  I edit my answer also.

Comment: @SamDaniel check now